# Vertical alignment between CALayer and CATextLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I'm currently working with CALayer and CATextLayer and I got a stuck when align them in vertical.
I'm create a CALayer for display an image inside it, then add a CATextLayer below CALayer after calculate the text size of CATexLayer, you can see my code for more details:

```
+ (instancetype)itemWithImage:(UIImage *)image andTitle:(NSString *)title {
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(MIN(image.size.width, [XFATLayoutAttributes itemWidth]), MIN(image.size.height, [XFATLayoutAttributes itemWidth]));
    CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
    layer.contents = (__bridge id)image.CGImage;
    layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, MIN(size.width, [XFATLayoutAttributes itemImageWidth]), MIN(size.height, [XFATLayoutAttributes itemImageWidth]));

    CATextLayer *label = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
    [label setFont:@"Helvetica"];
    [label setFontSize:14];
    label.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;

    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    label.string = title;
    label.foregroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:138/255.0 green:138/255.0 blue:143/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    label.wrapped = YES;
    label.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    CGSize stringSize = [title sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0]}];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(-5, layer.bounds.size.height + 5, stringSize.width, stringSize.height + 1);

    [layer addSublayer:label];

    return [[self alloc] initWithLayer:layer];
}
```

But the problem is the text size are not the same and my CATextLayer was misalignment a little bit like this image:
[image]

How can I align them in X axis? Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate right X offset this way:

```
label.frame = CGRectMake((size.width - stringSize.width) / 2, layer.bounds.size.height + 5,
                         stringSize.width, stringSize.height + 1);
```

Or you can simply make your `label` width equal to `image` width since you align text to center:

```
label.frame = CGRectMake(0, layer.bounds.size.height + 5,
                             size.width, stringSize.height + 1);
```

BTW I could not make work your method with `return [[self alloc] initWithLayer:layer]`, so I had to return constructed subclass instance itself:

```
AlignLayer *layer = [AlignLayer layer]; // my subclass
// ...
return layer;
```

And Apple [warns](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410842-initwithlayer?language=objc) against using `initWithLayer:` in such situations:

> This initializer is used to create shadow copies of layers, for example, for the presentationLayer method. Using this method in any other situation will produce undefined behavior. **For example, do not use this method to initialize a new layer with an existing layer’s content**.

Comment: Thanks mate, it's worked. I don't think it's very simple. Thanks again.